# RegEx for a conditional pattern in a string

Tags: r, regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I need to extract substrings from some strings,for example:
My data is a vector: `c("Shigella dysenteriae","PREDICTED: Ceratitis")`

```
a = "Shigella dysenteriae"

b = "PREDICTED: Ceratitis"
```

I hope that if the string starts with "PREDICTED:", it can be extracted to the subsequent word(maybe "Ceratitis"), and if the string doesn't start with "PREDICTED", it can be extracted to the first word(maybe Shigella);

**In this example, the result would be:**

```
result_of_a = "Shigella"

result_of_b = "Ceratitis"
```

Well,it is a typical conditional regular expression.I tried,but always failed;

I used `R` which can compatible `perl`'s regular expression.

I know R supports `perl`'s regular expression so I tried to use `regexpr` and `regmatches`, two functions to extract the substrings that I want.

The code  is :

```
pattern = "(?<=PREDICTED:)?(?(1)(\\s+\\w+\\b)|(\\w+\\b))"

a = c("Shigella dysenteriae")
m_a = regexpr(pattern,a,perl = TRUE)
result_a = regmatches(a,m_a)

b = c("PREDICTED: Ceratitis")
m_b = regexpr(pattern,a,perl = TRUE)
result_b = regmatches(b,m_b)
```

Finaly,the result is :

```
# result_a = "Shigella"
# result_b = "PREDICTED"
```

**It is not the result I expect,result_a is right,result_b is wrong.**

WHY???Its seem that the condition didn't work...

PS: 
   I tried to read some details of conditional reg-expresstion. this is the web I tried to read : https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html and I try to imitate "pattern" from this web ,and also tried to use "RegexBuddy" software to find the reason.

Comment: Are they in some kind of list, data frame or just independently stored?

Comment: vector，just like c("Shigella dysenteriae","PREDICTED: Ceratitis")

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason it does not work is because `(1)` [checks if a numbered capture group has been set](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html#check_numgroup) but there is no first capturing group set yet, also not in the positive lookbehind `(?<=PREDICTED:)?`.

There are a first and second capturing group in the parts that follow. The if clause will check for group 1, it is not set so it will match group 2.

If you would make it the only capturing group `(?<=(PREDICTED: )?)` and omit the other 2 then the if clause will be true but you will get an error because the lookbehind assertion is not [fixed length](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind_width).

Instead of using a conditional pattern, to get both words you might use a capturing group and make `PREDICTED:` optional:

```
^(?:PREDICTED: )?(\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PuKRSO/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/xomVHV)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:
To use the function below on a vector, one can do:
Vector: `myvec<-c("Shigella dysenteriae","PREDICTED: Ceratitis")`

```
lapply(myvec,extractor)
[[1]]
[1] "Shigella"

[[2]]
[1] "Ceratitis"
```

Or:

```
unlist(lapply(myvec,extractor))
[1] "Shigella"  "Ceratitis"
```

This assumes that the strings are always in the format shown above:

```
extractor<- function(string){
if(grepl("^PREDICTED",string)){
  strsplit(string,": ")[[1]][2]
}
  else{
    strsplit(string," ")[[1]][1]
  }

}
 extractor(b)
 #[1] "Ceratitis"
 extractor(a)
 #[1] "Shigella"
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to extract

- *the first word* after "PREDICTED:" if the strings starts with "PREDICTED:"
- *the first word* of the string if the string does not start with "PREDICTED:".

So, if there is no specific requirement to use only *one* regex, this is what I would do:

1. Remove any leading "PREDICTED:" (if any)
2. Extract the first word from the intermediate result.

For working with regex, I prefer to use Hadley Wickham's `stringr` package:

```
inp <- c("Shigella dysenteriae", "PREDICTED: Ceratitis")

library(magrittr) # piping used to improve readability
inp %>% 
  stringr::str_replace("^PREDICTED:\\s*", "") %>% 
  stringr::str_extract("^\\w+")
```

> ```
>  [1] "Shigella"  "Ceratitis"
> ```

To be on the safe side, I would remove any leading spaces beforehand:

```
inp %>% 
  stringr::str_trim() %>% 
  stringr::str_replace("^PREDICTED:\\s*", "") %>% 
  stringr::str_extract("^\\w+")
```

Comment: thank you  very much , this answer is easy to understand